# I wrote a simple clustering algorithm in Python but I don't get the intended result. Is my algorithm correct?

Tags: python, k-means

The data I'm working with is in a Pandas DataFrame with about a thousand rows looking like this

```
myData.head()
                Coordinates  Cluster
0   [53.044341, -2.2496476]  None
1  [53.1498286, -2.2358307]  None
2  [53.2562888, -1.9137567]  None
3  [53.2588584, -1.9120726]  None
4  [53.2588584, -1.9120726]  None
```

The Cluster column in myData will have the index number of the cluster they belong to, which is referenced in the clusterCenters DataFrame (20 clusters in length):

The cluster centers are generated by picking 20 random coordinates from myData like so:

```
clusterCenters = random.sample(myData['Coordinates'], 20)
clusterCenters.head()
           Clusters centers
0  [52.8901739, -2.1489866]
1  [53.3838042, -2.4839233]
2   [52.910345, -1.5138248]
3  [52.9816612, -2.1729386]
4  [53.3154335, -2.0873787]
```

I have two main functions, one to assign members to clusters and one to find the mean of the points to use within the algorithm.

```
def assignCluster(cluster_df,ccenters):
    # Add members to each cluster by finding difference between every cluster and the current coordinate and adding coordinate point to lowest difference.
    cluster_belong = []
    # For each post code coordinate
    for row in cluster_df.iterrows():
        co = row[1]['Coordinates']
        d = []
        # For each cluster center coordinate
        for index, cluster_co in ccenters.iterrows():
            d.append(distance.euclidean(cluster_co[0], co))
        # list d now has the distance between the current post code coordinate and every cluster center coordinate
        # append the index value (which is one of the cluster centers) for every post code coordinate
        cluster_belong.append(d.index(sorted(d)[0]))
        # for the moment, we will append the closest cluster center, but my goal is to append the closest cluster center that has less than 40 members already. (LC below) Is this even possible?
        # cluster_belong.append(d.index([x for index, x in enumerate(sorted(d)) if len(LBBL_df[LBBL_df['Cluster'] == index]) < 40][0])
    cluster_df['Cluster'] = cluster_belong
    return cluster_df

def find_CO_mean(cluster,mean_col):
    mean = [0,0]
    divisor = len(cluster['Coordinates'])
    for xx in cluster[mean_col]:
        mean = [mean[0]+float(xx[0]),mean[1]+float(xx[1])]

    mean = [mean[0]/divisor, mean[1]/divisor]
    return mean
```

And the loop that runs the functions and performs the clustering altogether

```
for iteration in range(50):
    #print(iteration)
    LBBL_df = assignCluster(LBBL_df, lbbl_ccenters)
    for x in lbbl_ccenters.iterrows():
        # get the old cluster center value
        oldcenter = lbbl_ccenters['Clusters centers'][x[0]]
        newcenter = [0,0]
        iterated = 0
        while oldcenter != newcenter:
            print(iterated)
            # create a filtered copy of LBBL_df dataframe with filter on cluster column to get all coordinates in that specific cluster
            filtered = LBBL_df[LBBL_df['Cluster'] == x[0]]
            # find new cluster center value through calculating mean
            newcenter = find_CO_mean(filtered,'Coordinates')
            oldcenter = newcenter
            # replace cluster center with new center calculated through finding mean
            lbbl_ccenters.iat[x[0],0] = newcenter
            # assign all coordinates to their closest cluster
            LBBL_df = assignCluster(LBBL_df, lbbl_ccenters)
            # refilter with updated cluster members
            filtered = LBBL_df[LBBL_df['Cluster'] == x[0]]
            # find new cluster center value again
            newcenter = find_CO_mean(filtered,'Coordinates')
            iterated+=1
```

But for some reason, the clustering doesn't work as intended. Here are the points plotted.

[image]

It's not very clear, but if you look closely you can see points that are not grouped properly. I want to know, is the logic of the algorithm sound? I know I'm not asking a specific question, but that's because I don't know what to ask. To me, the logic makes sense, but the results are incorrect.

Also as a bonus, I have a line commented out in the assignCluster function that groups a point to a cluster only if the length of the members of the cluster don't exceed 40. I've commented that out because this initial part needs to work properly first, before I get into further customization, but I would also appreciate if anyone could offer some insight into that as well. Thank you.

Comment: How do you know it's wrong? Have you tested it on a simple example where the correct answer is obvious?

Comment: Well, I'm fairly confident if I feed it simpler data that has say only 20 rows of coordinates, it would work. But, what do you mean simpler data? Like less rows? I think it's wrong because if you look at for example the pink cluster on the top, it has points that should be grouped with the cluster next to it, the red one. It's quite obviously located closer to the red cluster center than the pink.

Comment: By simpler data I mean for example two concentrated clusters far apart from one another, and run it with k=2. Or run it on a well-known dataset like iris and compare with the results of an established clusterer.

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation. I'll try it.

Comment: While I'm working on testing it on another dataset, could you let me know your thoughts on the code? Does it follow the correct procedure to achieve k-means?

Comment: On a very high level it looks right, but I won't check every detail (it's a bit hard to read for one thing -- more descriptive variable names and more docstrings would help). Personally though I would recommend a refactor to use vectorisation, either via `numpy` or `pandas` (which is largely just a wrapper for `numpy`). For instance, you can find the mean of n clusters stored in an nx2 array simply as `clusters.mean(axis=1)`, which is about 10 times less code. Use vector-like objects rather than lists. And putting lists in a DataFrame sometimes causes issues. If anything use separate columns.

Comment: thanks for the tips! yeah those are probably why the code is super slow

Comment: Indeed, one of the main reasons that "vectorisation" is done is that it is much faster. Python is a high level language, which means it it more expressive, but slower. Looping is particularly slow. Whereas a package like `numpy` actually uses the C language in the background, which is lower level and much faster, so if you can write everything in terms of vector operations instead of using Python loops it will speed up a lot.